# I want to send F12 keyboard command through STM32F0 to PC

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, interface

I want to send F12 command through STM32F0 microcontroller to PC through UART. I am getting the data on Hercules but PC not operate through that data. Only data received on Hercules .

Answer (score 7):

Change your STM32 firmware so that the device is seen as a HID device to PC, not a virtual COM port (UART) to send key presses.

Computers with security software on them might reject a custom HID device, as they might present a security risk.

Comment: Or composite device with both USB hid keyboard and USB cdc uart